# docker compose adding nodes dynamically to nginx frontend

Tags: docker-compose

Currently i have the configuration similar to below -

```
services:
  gunicorn:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.gunicorn
  restart: always
  ports:
    - 8001
  command: "something"

nginx:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile.nginx
  ports:
    - 80:80
  command: "/usr/sbin/nginx"
```

We want our gunicorn containers to scale dynamically & the configuration gets dynamically updated for new nodes in the nginx service .

Ideally if i scale using below command, configurations should get added automatically in nginx -

```
docker-compose scale gunicorn=2
```

I read about https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy for docker-compose , but i guess it needs to have the container configuration & VIRTUAL_HOST env passed for them to add dynamically in nginx config .

Please suggest .

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off trying to use a tool designed for this purpose. https://github.com/containous/traefik is one example.